# Page title does not change when error occurs in browser console angular 6

Tags: angular

I am setting page title of angular page using Title.

```
export class TitleService {

    constructor(private titleService: Title) {}

    setBrowserTitle(title: string) {
            this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

It works fine until any browser console error occurs.But after the console error the title does not change.When I refresh the page then things start working proper.

Comment: Kindly, elaborate error message.Moreover, you are passing parameter title in setBrowserTitle func and passing finalTitle in title service?

Comment: I have changed the name of variable its title. The errors are like ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null or undefined after then title change do not reflect.

Comment: from where you are assigning title param value(argument)?

Comment: from different components

Comment: That's not the case everytime.There may be error associated with component, using event emitter for setting title?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when I assign the current second to `document.title` every second via setInterval and forcing an error by accessing an undefined property after two seconds of application start. The title keeps changing. Could you please provide a minimal, reproducible example to showcase the error?

Comment: I also can't reproduce it when using the [`Title`-service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title#description).

Comment: Put this code in your example for setTitle function.However this is not the exact scenario.  list;

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    console.log('here' + newTitle);
    if(this.list[0].start){
      console.log('here');
    }
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }